# Find probability function

Tags: probability

> In a survey among people check whether they watch the evening news of Channel 6,5,61
>
> The data:
>
> 1. 20% watching Channel 5
> 2. 8% watching Channel 6
> 3. 10% watching Channel 61
>
> Also figure that 1% watching all the 3 Channels.
>   10% watching 2 Channels.
>
> Define X - the number of channels being watched. What is the probability function?

**I thought about it this way:**

$$P(x=3)=0.01$$

$$P(x=2)=0.1$$

$$P(A∩B) + P(B∩C) + P(A∩C)=0.1$$

$$P(A∩B∩C)=0.01$$

And from the Inclusion–exclusion principle:
    $$P(A∪B∪C) = P(A) + P(B) + P(C) - P(A∩B) - P(B∩C) - P(A∩C) + P(A∩B∩C)$$
So:
$$P(A∪B∪C) = 0.2 + 0.08 + 0.1 - (0.1) + 0.01$$
$$P(A∪B∪C) = 0.29$$

So $P(x=0)=1-P(A∪B∪C)=0.71$ And $P(x=1)=0.18$

But the answer in the book it`s $P(x=0)=0.74$ And $P(x=1)=0.15$

Why my idea not working? 
Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The crucial mistake here is $P(A \cap B) + P(B \cap C) + P(A \cap C)$ is not equal to the probability of picking a 2-channels watchers, because it will "triple" count those 3-channels watchers also. The probability of picking a 2-channels watchers will be

$$P(A \cap B) + P(B \cap C) + P(A \cap C) - 3P(A \cap B \cap C) $$